# Who discovered that normalizer of an abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup controls $p$-transfer?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, math-history, transfer-theory

**Theorem**: Let $G$ be a finite group and let $P\in Syl_p(G)$ and assume $P$ is abelian. Then $N_G(P)$ controls $p$-transfer.

I wonder who discovered above theorem? Is it due to Burnside?

Comment: I don't know whether Burnside was aware of it, but the proof of Burnside's Transfer Theorem (or at least the proof I am familiar with) can easily be adapted to show that, when $P$ is abelian, the image of the transfer $T:G \to P$ projects onto $P/[N_G(P),P]$, from which I think your theorem follows.