# simplicity of the Janko group $J_1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

In [the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186936690010X?via%3Dihub), Janko shows the simplicity of Janko group $J_1$ at the Lemma 2.1. In this proof it says "By a transfer theorem all involutions are conjugate in $G$", but I cannot understand.

1. Some propositions are named "transfer theorem", such as Burnside's transfer theorem, Thompson's transfer theorem, etc... . I want to know which proposition is used.
2. I found [an Additional description for the proof](http://www.joebohanon.com/math/J1.pdf), but this part of proof is not correct (because the author uses the result of the Janko's paper, and the original proof doesn't use any specific calculations). I want to know theoretic approach of the problem.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the statement is as follows: a finite group $G$ with three properties (a) all Sylow 2-group of $G$ is abelian (b) $G$ doesn't have subgroups index 2 (c) $G$ has an involution $t$ and $C_G(t)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathfrak{A}_5$, then $G$ is simple.

Answer (score 7):

The group in question is simple and has elementary abelian Sylow 2-subgroups of order 8.

A crucial fact that you need to know is that, if finite group $G$ has an abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$, then $p$-transfer is controlled by $N_G(P)$ - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626511) for example.

This means that the largest $2$-quotient of $G$ (which is trivial by assumption) is isomorphic to the largest $2$-quotient of $N_G(P)$.

Now $N_G(P)/C_G(P) \le {\rm Aut}(P) \cong {\rm GL}(3,2)$. If $|N_G(P)/C_G(P)|$ is divisible by $7$, then the involutions in $P$ are all conjugate under an element of order $7$. That is what we are trying to prove.

Now $|{\rm GL}(3,2)| = 8 \times 3 \times 7$, and $|N_G(P)/C_G(P)|$ is odd, so the only other options are $|N_G(P)/C_G(P)| = 1$ or $3$. In both cases, the action is reducible with at least one element of order $2$ centralizex by $N_G(P)$, and then $N_G(P)$ has a quotient group of order $2$. Hence so does $G$, contradicting the assumption.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I doubt this answer uses the simplicity of $J_1$, is this a circular reasoning?

Comment: Yes you are right. But we are assuming that $G$ has no subgroup of index $2$, which is enough for this argument to work.

Comment: I have another question. In the latter of the proof, you use the result "the Sylow $2$-group of $J_1$ is $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$". Is it necessary of the proof (or is the result easy to show) ?

Comment: This follows from the given assumptions that the Sylow $2$-subgroups are abelian, and that the centralizer of an element $t$ of order $2$ has the structure $C_G(t) = C_2 \times A_5$.

Comment: I had misunderstood, but we could calculate the concrete structure of Sylow 2-subgroup... . As you say we can take the subgroup of $C_G(t)$ isomorphic to the $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$, and $|C_G(t)|=120=2^3\times 15$, so it's the maximal 2-subgroup of $C_G(t)$. In addition to that, if we take the Sylow 2-group $P$ which includes $\langle t\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, then $P$ must be the subgroup of $C_G(t)$ because $P$ is abelian from the assumption (a). So the Sylow 2-group of $J_1$ is $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$.